# passwordless ssh from linux to Solaris works for oracle user but not for ftpuser

Tags: linux, ssh, passwords, solaris, public-key

The public key from the same linux box is set up for 2 users in Solaris, which are oracle and fptuser.  And the passwordless ssh works from the same linux box to Solaris for oracle user, but not the ftpuser.

When doing the 'ssh ftpuser@solaris_box' from the linux, it asks for the password.

I noticed that one difference between the oracle and ftpuser is the Solaris login shell in the /etc/passwd file.  The oracle has /bin/ksh and ftpuser has /bin/bash.

Can this be the cause of the problem or are there other things that could be the problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the user's shell is `ksh` or `bash` is certainly not the cause of this issue. The usual culprits are too relaxed permissions on either the home directory, the `.ssh` directory, or the files under the `.ssh` directories.

Comment: I rechecked the .ssh directory, and it has 755 permission. I changed it to 700. The .ssh/authorized_keys has 644 and I changed to 600. But it still asks for the password. Do you need to restart the sshd? I do not have the authority.  Another difference I noticed is that the home directory for the ftpuser is not /home/ftpuser in the /etc/passwd file.  Could this be the cause?  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: The location of the home directory doesn't matter but its owner and permissions definitely do. You do not tell if you checked them. There should be no need to restart the ssh daemon for these changes.

Comment: I double-checked the owner of the dir and file, and it is ftpuser. Another thing I noticed is that the home dir is  /abc.ftpuser and its permission is 775.  If I post the debug msg from  'ssh -v ftpuser@solaris_box',  will it help?  Thank you very much.

Comment: The homedir permissions are wrong (as far as ssh is concerned). It shouldn't be writable by anyone in the owner's group like it is currently. Only the owner should have writing rights in its home directory. `chmod 0755 ~ftpuser` will fix it.

Comment: jiliagre, thank you very much for the reply.  After you mentioned homedir permissions, I checked again the home dir, and I found out that the homedir owner is appmgr and ftpuser is the groupname.  So, it is like drwxrwxr-x appmgr ftpuser 3584 Aug 13 abc.ftpuser.        I think this is the reason. I never thought that the owner is appmgr, not the ftpuser.  Thank you very much for leading me to find this.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer then. You can still do it even while the question is on hold or closed.